# Round a submission value from SESSION + shortcode with 2 decimals

Tags: php, mollie

Can someone explain me what is wrong with this **AFTER** line of code.

BEFORE (EXAMPLE - HOW TO USE):

```
"value" => "27.50" //enforce the use of strings
```

**AFTER**:

```
"value" => "round($_SESSION["Payment_Amount"], 2)" //Think of that Payment_Amount is 198,99 in session.
```

An explanation why it goes wrong would be very appreciated.

Comment: it's in quotes.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It must be?

Comment: Remove the outer double quotes around `"round($_SESSION["Payment_Amount"], 2)"`. The function won't be executed inside the quotes, for one, and the unescaped inner double quotes are probably causing a syntax error

Comment: @Don'tPanic Is there no different approach possible without removing those quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a formatting function like `sprintf` or `number_format` instead of `round`.

```
"value" => sprintf('%0.2f', $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"])
```

For two reasons:

1. It will return a string. It looks like you're quoting the value because you need it to be a string.
2. It will display two digits after the decimal point. It looks like that's what you want, and `round` won't show them if there happen to be trailing zeros, because it returns a float, and floats don't show trailing zeros when they're converted to strings.

Comment: Thats what I needed! Thank you very much!